# Python ElementTree - Taking Element.Text from HTML form_input

Tags: python, html, xml, forms

So I have a basic script which creates xml and adds it to a file:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

root = Element('ipaddress')
tree = ElementTree(root)
ipaddress = Element('ipaddress')
root.append(ipaddress)
ipaddress.text= **INSERT FROM FORM**
ipaddress.set('version', 'v4')

print etree.tostring(root)
tree.write("/root/Desktop/" + "xmlfile.xml")
```

It out puts like this on xmlfile.xml

```
<ipaddress><ipaddress version="v4">123.123.123.123</ipaddress></ipaddress>
```

I have a simple HTML Form element to handle it:

```
<form action="create_ticket" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <input type="text" size="35" placeholder="Host IP"
                name="host_ip" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
       </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The form is much larger with more inputs but this is the basic idea. It also serves a ticket through API by using another script.

How do I dynamically change the ipaddress.text value based on what the user inputs to host_ip on the form?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Strictly speaking "What I need to do is take the value of host_ip and insert on the xml generator the value that the user inputs for ipaddress.text" is a statement, not a question. Can you rephrase to clarify what you need help with?

Comment: Ok my apologies. So as per above I have a web form. I also have an XML file with the value like above. I want to be able to dynamically change that xml value based on user input in the form but I don't know how

Comment: Edited to make the question clearer